# What is the best way of getting all model instances of an the authenticated user?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

If you have an authenticated user, what is the best way (in terms of performance) of getting all of the instances of a specified related model (i.e. get all of the authenticated user's posts)?

1)

```
Auth::user()->posts
```

2)

```
Post::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get()
```

3) Other Ideas?

*Note: for this example, assume that user have many posts and a post belongs to user.

Comment: Both methods execute the same SQL query. Although it should be `Auth::user()->posts` without the `()`. Assuming the relationships are set in the `User` model of course.

Comment: There isn't much point to option 2 in this instance, as option 1 is cleaner, and can be extended to include more logic if you need it, like `Auth::user()->posts()->where(...)->get();`

Comment: @Adnan option one is fine. You can achieve that by establishing relationship between User and Post.